# error The argument type 'File?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File'

Tags: flutter, flutter-image-picker

How do I fix it? Changed the variables and it still shows an error. As before, there is a line on getimage, how do I change it? The argument type 'File?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File'.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEQu9.png)

I hope you guys can help me fix the problem. Thanks.

Comment: It would help to be able to see, and possibly run parts of your code.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/238704)

Answer (score 0):

`Image.file(file)` is flagged as an error because file is nullable and most likely of type `File?`. You already handled the null case hence `Image.file(file!)` is the not-null case and fixes your issue.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it as you said and it now runs normally

Comment: Oh great. You may want to mark this as the accepted answer and or upvote.